# Meteor packages for ranking/voting/scoring

Tags: meteor, package, atmosphere

Do you know if there is any package for ranking options other than `ideorecall:referral` or `barbatus:stars-rating`?

I'd like that each post of my site gets a score depending on the visitors rating.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barbatus is more than adequate for that. If you don't want a pre-made package, check out page 234 of the "Discover Meteor" book, which you can purchase online at their website discovermeteor.com. The voting chapter gives a detailed outline of how to "roll your own" voting system that stores votes and also voter data as well. Very easy to implement and customize